# SQL Display table information, when condition true in another table?

Tags: php, sql

So I have 2 tables that I'm using.  A product table that will fill out some product cards using PHP.  What I want to do if make an sql statement to only pull information from the product table if the user has failed a red/green or blue/yellow colorblind test that we setup.  So if the user has failed a red/green colorblind test, I want to only pull the product information from the products that have a lenstype of red.  And the designation of if they have failed the test is marked as a 1.

Looking for an SQL statement to make this happen.

Userreg

| id | bluefail | redfail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |

Product

| prodtitle | lenstype | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 10 |
| 2 | red | 10 |
| 3 | red | 10 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` like this:

```
select u.*, p.*
from userreg u join
     product p
     on (p.lenstype = 'blue' and u.bluefail = 1) or
        (p.lenstype = 'red' and u.redfail = 1);
```

Note that if a user fails both, then they will get products for both types.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to work.  Im obviously kind of new to SQL, but im placing this statement in my PHP. 

$sql = "SELECT u.*, p.*
        FROM userregistration u join 

        product p

        on (p.lenstype = 'blue' and bluefail = 1) or

           (p.lenstype = 'red' and redfail = 1);




Im getting a syntax error I suppose.  Because the page itself wont work.